# How to check the class attribution dynamically?

Tags: python

```
class  test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.height=int(input("how height are you"))
    def fun(self,x):
        print(x+self.height)
for i in range(1,10):
    test().fun(i)
```

The code will be executed 9 times.  Every time, a window with `how height are you` pops up, and you can input a value.

Now what I want is for `self.height` to be fixed the first time I enter a value and for there to be no more `how height are you` pop-ups from the second time (that is to say `i=1`) onwards.

```
class  test():
    def __init__(self):
        if (  self.height has no value):  
            self.height=int(input("how height are you"))
    def fun(self,x):
        print(x+self.height)

for i in range(1,10):
    test().fun(i)
```

How to fill it with some code or change it into other structure?

Comment: You're making a new `test` on every iteration, whereas you seem to only want one. Use something like the following (with appropriate whitespace) `t = test(); for i in range(1,10): t.fun(i)`

Comment: That code will execute 9 times since range is non-inclusive for the stop integer.

Answer (score 1):

You are instantiating `test()` every iteration of the loop, which runs the `__init__` function (and resets instance members).

I think what you want to do is instantiate `test` outside the loop:

```
testObject = test()
```

and use the object in the loop:

```
for i in range(1,10):
    testObject.fun(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Only create a single `test` object once (before the `for` loop) and you'll only have to input a value once:

```
class  test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.height=int(input("How tall are you? "))
    def fun(self,x):
        print(x+self.height)

obj = test()
for i in range(1,10):
    obj.fun(i)
```

(I also took the liberty of correcting the input prompt.)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by creating and object of the function and passing it through the loop.

```
class  test():
def __init__(self):
    self.height=int(input("How tall are you? "))
def fun(self,x):
    print(x+self.height)
Theobject = test()
for m in range(1,10):
obj.fun(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Factory` class to produce the `Test` instances dynamically, like the following:

```
class Test(object):

    def __init__(self, height):
        self.height = height

    def fun(self, x):
        print(x + self.height)

class TestFactory(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.height = None

    def test(self):
        if self.height is None:
            self.height = int(input("how height are you"))
        return Test(self.height)

fac = TestFactory()
for i in range(1,10):
    fac.test().fun(i)
```

In this case `Test` is a normal class of static initialization, but you assign initial parameter dynamically. This is quite a common practice in `Java`.